# JQuery each function returning duplicate text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The jQuery attached is very close to working.  It is returning (or appending) text twice.

I am iterating through an unordered list and appending a querystring paramter to the hrefs.

The `?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document` is being appending twice, like this:

```
http://www.google.com?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
//foreach item in the quick launch, add a parameter to ensure the Ribbon is set to the Document tab
    $('#zz18_V4QuickLaunchMenu ul li').each(function() {    
        $(this).find('a').attr('href', function (i, val) {          
            return val + '?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document';
        });
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to make the text only append once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `each()`.

```
$('#zz18_V4QuickLaunchMenu ul li a').attr('href', function (i, val) {          
  return val + '?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document';
});
```

There should be no appending the string twice with this code. (FWIW, there should be no appending the string twice with your code, either.)

Comment: Excellent.  That worked.  Do you know how I can append the querystring to only hrefs that contain 'leg'?

Comment: @obautista Your's should have worked, too. -- Either use `$('#zz18_V4QuickLaunchMenu ul li a[href*="leg"]')` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)) **or** use `return val + ( /leg/.test(val) ? '' : '?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document' );`.

Comment: Do I need the "test" in:  return val + ( /leg/.test(val) ? '' : '?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document' );

Comment: @obautista Is this an interactive JavaScript training session?

Answer (score 0):

It must be running twice because you have selected two `<li>` elements. `.each()` is iterative and is running twice, once for each element.

Comment: If there are two `<li>` elements, it will run twice. Once for each `<li>` element. It will not run twice for the same element, but that's wht the OP seems to see.